# Поиск даты вида "February 4,2000" в Java

Tags: java, строки, дата, шаблоны-проектирования

"Все даты представить в формате «dd.mm.yyyy», для этого воспользоваться соответствующим классом для манипуляций датами/временем: java.time.LocalDate. Класс входит в состав базовой JRE Java 8." - задание. Для решения мне нужно найти в строке дату вида February 8, 1992. Пробовал матчить с паттерном вида ".\w{8,}\s\d{1,2}.\s\d{1,4}". Не находит. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

update: понял в чем была проблема паттерна. Вот правильный)) ".\w{1,8}\s\d{{1,2}.\s\d{1,4}"